# Keeping comments in Word after deleting associated text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using the newest version of Microsoft Word (2017) and want the comments in the review pane to remain. Every time I delete the text that comment relates to, the comment disappears entirely. How do I delete the text while keeping the comment displayed in the right-hand pane?

Comment: This behaviour is by design. Each comment is considered to be child of a range of text. If you delete the text then it child is deleted too.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with a workaround.  Put whitespace into the commented text.

Say you have some commented text, it shows in Word with brackets:
[image: Text with comment]

Insert some whitespace, e.g. just a space within this text.  Not at either the beginning or the end.
[image: Text with a space]

Now delete the text but leave the space between the brackets:
[image: Blank space with a comment]

You now have a comment applied to no text, only to a space.
You have not deleted the commented text, just edited it to a space.
This isn't ideal as the presence of a space at that point of your document may not be convenient.  However, it does provide a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check thoroughly, but I just found out that the comment remains in place if I delete the text word-by-word (ctrl-del or ctrl-backspace). The idea of a comment being a child to text makes sense, but if I keep the deleted text visible through "track changes", I want the comment to remain visible as well (so as to communicate to editors, indeed).

Comment: That's another story. If you use change tracking then text won't be actually deleted, therefore comments starry too; that's independent how  exactly you've deleted the text.

Comment: @Mate Juhasz: No - deleting anchor text with track changes keeps the anchor text deletion, but deletes the comment.  If you later go back through and reject deletion, the comment does not reappear.

Comment: Deleting character by character works on Word for Mac v16.47, it leaves the comment in place. Only if you highlight the text and press delete does it also delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use strike-out font for the deleted text.  You'll need to remember to delete it properly later when accepting tracked changes.  The comments will remain for the reviewers so they remember the reasons why the text was ultimately deleted.